# How to send mails from an array in Swift Mailer?

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I have two arrays consisting of a list emails which I need to send through swift mailer.
Here is the format of the array

```
$array1 = Array ( [0] => test1@testserver1.com [1] => test2@testserver1.com)
$array2 = Array ( [0] => test1@testserver2.com [1] => test2@testserver2.com)
```

In Swift Mailer, I tried sending mail like this

```
->setTo(array($array1,$array2))
```

but it is resulting in an error.

Can some one please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTo` accepts *an* array. You'll want to merge your arrays into one:

```
->setTo(array_merge($array1, $array2));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I got it working like this. But still is there a way where we can pass multiple arrays.

Comment: Glad to help. Please remember to "checkmark" (and upvote) the answer. You'll need to use `array_merge` whenever multiple arrays are involved.